# Checking Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] on every request

Tags: asp.net

I am using this code to check if the request came from a page , if not then redirect somewhere.

```
string referer = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(referer))
            {
                Response.Redirect("/UnauthorizedAccess.aspx");
            }
```

It is working , I don't know whether it is perfect the solution.However I am checking this on load event of one of my page.How can I make it check on every request.Should I check this for all my pages.Also it is a good approach.Can anybody point me in the right direction.Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: what you intend to do by checking this on every request?

Comment: @Furqan I am trying to restrict user from writing url manually and copy paste.

Comment: are you storing the previous page url in referer variable?

Comment: then consider using masterpage

Comment: @DigitalAssets You are trying to tell me that I should check it on load of master page , is it , correct me pls if I am wrong.

Comment: yep, the answer is posted down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have logic that you would like to be run on the OnLoad of a bunch of your pages. You should probably create a `BasePage` that derives from `Page` and have the logic inside. Then all the pages you want that logic in can derive from `BasePage` instead of the regular `Page`.

Another approach can be using [Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)

**Note:** After reading OPs additional comments. One thing to look out for when using a Master Page is that the Master Page's Page_Load event happens AFTER the Content Page's Page_Load event. 
In other words the lifecycle is like this:

Master Page **Init** Event

Content Page **Init** Event

Content Page **Load** Event

Master Page **Load** Event

If your response.redirect moves the user to another page with the same master page (and same "validation" check) you might find yourself in an endless loop :)

Comment: Basically I am trying o prevent users from writing url manually and preventing copy paste

Comment: Then both approaches can work. Master Pages are basically more for having the same layout on all pages, but it also has Page_Init and Page_Load events.

Comment: I tried it in load event of master page , but in chrome It said this webpage has a redirect loop.

Comment: Please post the code you used in the Load event of the master page. Sounds like you were in the right direction but might have had a small bug...

Comment: Should I redirect to some page without Master page.

Comment: Yes, your UnauthorizedAccess.aspx page should not be a page that has the HTTP_REFERER check inside it (so if your check is in a master page, it shouldn't have that master page)...

Comment: I am using an Error page , it is not using master page.Now the problem is , when I run the application it is redirecting to Error page only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12797/discussion-between-blachshma-and-freebird)

Answer (score 2):

If you have lot of pages, with these kind of common codes, than one possible solution is creating your own `MyPage` class as a child of the standard `Page` class. In your `MyPage` you can use something like:

```
Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string referer = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(referer))
            {
                Response.Redirect("/UnauthorizedAccess.aspx");
            }
base.Page_Load(sender, e);
}
```

Then any of your pages can inherit from this own `MyPage` class instead of the .NET's standard one.

In this way the common code reside in one place. In case of any change you have to modify that only there.

Or another possibility, you can consider using Master Pages.

Comment: Thanks for the help.How can I use master page to achieve this , can you explain a bit.

Comment: I think the link in Blachshma's comment exmplain that pretty well:  [Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)

Comment: I am already using master page , what I am asking is should I check it in the load event of master page.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. If you already using a master page, than I think that's the easier way to go with for you.

Comment: I will try it , but do you think it is a good approach , is it secure enough.

Comment: I dont' thikn about it from a security perspective. I do not think it can be more dangerous than checking it on every page. What are your concerns exactly using it on the master page?

Comment: I just wanted to know will it work properly , is the solution foolproof.Also when I used it in page load of master page it says This webpage has a redirect loop.

Comment: I think there should not be a problem with that. Redirect loop is possible, if your `UnauthorizedAccess.aspx` page uses the master page too. Because then the check runs again after the redirection. So you should check if the target page is the `UnauthorizedAccess.aspx` page already, in which case this check and redirection is not necessary.

Comment: What can be done , can you post an example it is a bit confusing for me.Thanks.

Comment: I mean just put an `if` expression around your original `if` statement. In that check the actual requested page. If that is NOT the  `UnauthorizedAccess.aspx` page, than do the original check too and redirect. If you are already requested for the `UnauthorizedAccess.aspx` page, than just skip the check, since you are already redirected and certainly do not want to redirect yourself any more. You are already on the `UnauthorizedAccess.aspx` page. In this way you can eliminate the infinite loop of redirection.